# Make a DIV to take the remainder of the parent's width -AND- to also take the parent's height

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors, tailwind-css

We have this markup:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-1">
      Hello World!
   </div>
   <div class="child-2">
   </div>
</div>
```

`child-1` width is 30%, and we need `child-2` to take the remainder of the parent's width, so we have:

```
.child-1{
   width:30%;
}
.child-2{
   float: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

And it works. But we also need `child-2` to take the parent's height, so we added flex to the parent:

```
.parent{
   display:flex
}
```

And it works. However, `child-2` is no longer taking the reminder of the parent width.

If we define `child-2` width to a fixed number, such as 70%, it works. However, for the script we are doing, we need it to take the remainder of the parent with.

Is there a way to make `child-2` to take the remainder of the parent width -AND- to take the parent height without having to defined its width to a fixed number?

Comment: Give `.child-2` a `flex: 1` ?

Comment: You can tell child-2 to consume remaining space with `flex-grow`. No need for floats or overflow. https://jsfiddle.net/752rhuna/

Comment: @HaoWu Yes it worked thank you so much

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Yes, thank you for the insight, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make child-2 take the remaining width of the parent and also take the parent's height without specifying a fixed width. You can achieve this using the "flex-grow" property. Here's how to do it:

```
  .parent {
       display: flex;
    }
    
    .child-1 {
       width: 30%;
    }
    
    .child-2 {
       flex-grow: 1; /* This will make it take the remaining width */
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```

By setting flex-grow to 1 for child-2, it will automatically expand to fill the remaining width of the parent while still taking the parent's height. This way, you don't need to specify a fixed width for child-2, and it will adapt to the available space in the parent container.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I love you pal